# Nginx, Wordpress, and SQL

Tags: wordpress, nginx, docker

I currently am trying to learn how to use docker and was wondering if there is a way to make a Docker stack that includes Wordpress, SQL, and Nginx.

Right now I want to have 3 containers running, 1 for each and use nginx as a reverse proxy for my wordpress app.

However, every time I attempt to get this stack up and running through a composer file, only Wordpress and SQL get linked, but not the Nginx.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:fpm
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

This is all I have in my docker-compose.yml

Comment: It would be useful see your Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml

Comment: Without a link/depend command between nginx and wordpress, you won't see any links there. How do you intend to use these containers together, since wordpress includes a web interface? Have you attempted to use the DNS based container discovery?

Comment: helloMundo can you explain what you mean exactly by the Nginx container doesn't get linked? We may need to see the nginx conf file, this should work. @BMitch - fyi, with latest versions the discovery in a default docker-compose config should be automatic with no need for explicit link attributes unless you need them for aliases or load order.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic approach should work. I have a feeling there is a configuration issue somewhere, possibly with nginx that is preventing it from working as you intend.

You can try this similar docker-compose.yml file as a sample to see how it may differ from what you are doing:

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     links:
       - mysql:db
     depends_on:
       - mysql

  mysql:
    image: k0st/alpine-mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass 

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/files:/var/www/nginx:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
```

**`nginx/nginx.conf`**

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  sendfile  off;
  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://php;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_redirect     off;
    }
  }
}
```

The nginx config is simplified but that should work for testing -- basically all it's doing is proxying the php app. Maps to port 81 to avoid conflicts on the host. (Note this is just a rough demo, would need to be fleshed out for any use more than that.)

Regarding linking, you can see that if you run: `docker-compose exec mysql ping -c2 nginx` to ping from the mysql container to the nginx container, you will succeed even though there are no links specified between these containers. Docker Compose will maintain those links in the default network for you.

If you like, you can fetch a working version [from this repo here](https://github.com/lgelfan/docker-compose-lamp) and run `docker-compose up`, and (assuming you don't have anything running on port 81) see results on http://localhost:81/ (or whatever your corresponding hostname/IP is).

For more info on Docker Compose networking see:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   *reachable* by other containers on that network, and *discoverable* by them at a hostname identical to the container name.
>
> Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is
>   reachable from another service. They are not required to enable
>   services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other
>   service at that service’s name.

Comment: Note the above sample uses phpmyadmin instead of Wordpress for simplified demo and less config to manage. The basic flow should be the same for any similar PHP app (i.e., one that links from its container to a mysql container).

Comment: just out of curiosity, what does the :ro mean after the `./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro`

Comment: :ro is for read-only, purely optional but just signifies that the files are not meant to be changed from within the container. This set-up is mostly to make development and testing easier. For a production workflow you might copy the config file into the image via `build` process for better portability and immutability.

Comment: So for `./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro` this means we are going to take our `./nginx/nginx.conf` and when the container is up, we are going to move it to`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro' but have the nginx.conf be a read only file?

Comment: Yes, essentially. It will be mounted (not moved) to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro` inside the container as read-only. But like I mentioned, the read-only attribute is optional. Using the volume lets you adjust the settings in that file externally and restart the container and have the changes persist.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the [jwilder-nginx](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) docker image. It is using docker-gen to detect containers, and will register them in nginx.conf.

This should work, if you add "VIRTUAL_HOST" the domain will be added to nginx.conf. Please note: You don't have to expose ports on WordPress with this Setup. jwilder-nginx will use default port to forward traffic.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:fpm
    links:
      - db
      - nginx
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      VIRTUAL_HOST: myblog.mydomain.de
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: Would I need to create an nginx.conf file? I am very new to nginx and not sure what all the files are needed

Comment: I get an error when I attempt to compose on the VIRTUAL_HOST line. " yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 22, column 7"

Comment: Sorry my failure: VIRTUAL_HOST: whatever.de